# Write an answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

How can I write an answer that includes code on Stack Overflow?

I wrote an answer, but don't be shown completely and I read Stack Overflow's help, but it doesn't help me.
Which tag and sign must be used for a code that I want to be run for you in an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code embedded with text, `<form action="like this">`, - surround in back ticks

One line - indent four spaces (or one tab -- *tabs must be inserted outside the StackOverflow editor, such as in your IDE, and copy/pasted)*

Lengthy section - copy from code editor (your IDE, such as Notepad++) with entire section indented (at least) one tab space (each line). *Most IDEs let you select a section of text, press TAB, and the entire section is indented on additional tab. Note that this allows you preserve existing indenting, which is very desirable.*

Full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

---

Undocumented trick: Numbered lists can be tricky to work with, so do this:

(1) First point

(2) Second point

(3) etc

[tab] Your code now formats correctly
[tab] Another line of code

---

Final tip: Below all questions/answers is **Edit** link. Go ahead and "edit" other peoples' posts and see how they did things, then exit without saving.

Comment: instead of showing how to avoid numbered lists, why not show how to nest them, as well as code-blocks, by increasing indentation?